# PHP recursively search through subfolders for filenames containing a certain substring and rename that substring with another string

Tags: php

I have a cache folder that contains many other folders.  In each of these folders are images (each folder contains a series of images for a particular product).  The filenames are in the format something like:

```
image1-1200x1800.jpg
image1-40x40.jpg
image1-480x600w.jpg
```

For this example, I'm trying to search through the subfolders of the cache directory and rename all the substrings "image1" that are found in the filenames to "great", so the above would be renamed to:

```
great-1200x1800.jpg
great-40x40.jpg
great-480x600w.jpg
```

I have the following but the path to the files is unknown - it could be in any subfolder of the cache directory":

```
<?php

if ($handle = opendir('/path/to/files')) {
    while (false !== ($fileName = readdir($handle))) {
        $newName = str_replace("image1","great",$fileName);
        rename($fileName, $newName);
    }
    closedir($handle);
}
?>
```

Any help would be much appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recursion means you have function calling itself. You could make a function which calls itself with the pathname if the current "file" is a directory.

But fortunately you can use a recursive iterator which is included in PHP.

```
$search = 'image1';
$replace = 'great';
$path = '/path/to/files/';

$iterator = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path);
foreach(new RecursiveIteratorIterator($iterator) as $file) {
    if ($file->isFile() && str_contains($file->getFilename(), $search)) {
        rename($file->getPathName(), str_replace($search, $replace, $file->getPathName()));
    }
}
```

**Note:** `str_contains()` works with PHP8+
For prior versions use

```
false !== strpos($file->getFilename(), $search)
```